# How to get matched data into database?

Tags: file, ssis, lookup, flat

I took a flat file and looked up a field in a database and added another field as a new column to the flat file.

But when I directed the matched output to another database, the matched field is NULL upon inspection with a Select statement.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Flat file data -> lookup component -> ? You perform a lookup and get the matched data. Do you do anything with the data, like write it to a database?

Comment: Does your Dataviwer show values after the lookup step?

Comment: I directed the matched data to a database.  The viewer does show the data to be found and matched.

Comment: What is your lookup component set up to do with unmatched rows?

Answer (score 0):

I would check for any of the following on either the flat file or lookup data, which may cause a non-match:
- text data with trailing blanks
- text data with upper case vs lower case
- numeric data of varying datatypes, even just precisions
- probably other issues I haven't listed above - it's just ridiculously fussy

To avoid these issues I always explicitly use SQL CAST or Derived Column transforms to make sure the key fields are all text, all upper case and all exactly the same, byte by byte.